# How to prevent adding extra empty lines before documented items during code formatting in IDEA/Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA for Kotlin and have a nice enum with documented items:

```
enum class TestEnum {
  /** A comment for the item #1. */
  ITEM1,
  /** A comment for the item #2. */
  ITEM2,
  /** A comment for the item #3. */
  ITEM3
}
```

It look nice and pretty. But when I use automatic code formatting it make it like this:

```
enum class TestEnum {
  /** A comment for item #1. */
  ITEM1,

  /** A comment for item #2. */
  ITEM2,

  /** A comment for item #3. */
  ITEM3
}
```

It an an adds empty line before every comment. If there are a lot of items and especially if it's a nested enum it's starting to look ugly and hard to read. The same this happens with documented properties or methods.

Is there any setting to prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

This behavior was implemented recently in the Kotlin plugin 1.3.70. I created a request to disable it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-37420. Please follow this issue for updates.

The workaround is to use an older version of Kotlin plugin (1.3.61).